# Can you generate scaffolding for a Zend Framework 2 app

Tags: zend-framework2

I've been doing searches on scaffolding in Zend Framework 2 but so far have not been able to get scaffolding up and working.

By "scaffolding" I'm referring to a way to point your tool at a database and have it generate views/forms to perform CRUD operations.

This can be useful for quickly prototyping something, and/or build a rough admin tool for some of your database tables.

It can also provide a starting point for some form you are building.

Is this possible in Zend Framework 2?

Comment: This would be a nice project, especially if you can leverage Doctrine 2's metadata, then you only need to code up your entities and the tools can give you your db tables AND your fieldsets, forms, controllers and views. I tend to think that this isn't currently available for ZF2, as it's been released relatively recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the answer to this is "this feature does not exist yet."

Oh well!

Comment: How about **making** this feature? :)

Comment: Actually, this one looks good: http://clintberry.com/2010/zend-framework-code-generator-with-scaffolding/